# UITableView row height not drawing taller with text

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, ios4

I'm trying to mimic the address cell in Address Book / Contacts App.

I want a cell with style `UITableViewCellStyleValue2` to display an address such as:

```
// 123 Fake St.
// Suite 555
// Denver CO, 80000
```

But actual cell isn't drawing the way I want.  The label is drawing outside the bounds of the tableview row and part of top of the label is being cut off by the row directly above it.

Here's what I have so far:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
cell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; //doesn't seem to do anything
self.tableView.rowHeight = 88.0f; // default is 44.0
cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0; //unlimited lines
```

An `NSLog` statement confirmed the `rowHeight` is set to 88.0.

I realize a delegate method exists to change the row height.  However, in my current app I only need this one cell to expand with the text, so I didn't feel it necessary to implement the delegate method.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that setting row height this way (self.tableView.rowHeight = 88.0f;) for a single row will work. You should implement the delegate method which in your case is very simple, i.e.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return ([indexPath row] == MY_TALLER_CELL_ROW) ? 88.0f : 44.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll probably have more luck not using the cell's default `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` views; instead, create your own labels and add them to the cell's content view.